# Is possible to create a font in photoshop and convert it later for use in windows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I would like to create a own font in photoshop like an image, and convert it later to use my font in many cases.

Anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two ways. The incorrect one and the correct one.

The incorrect is using Photoshop. The correct is using a special software to do that.

Some options are

Fontographer, Font forge. Corel Draw allows to export thoose too.

Take a look at this google search.

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=fontographer+alternative

The reason for using a special software is that there are a loot of info that needs to be adresed, what font it is when you type a key, what is the baseline, the kerning, etc.

---

In photoshop you can make a letterhead sign, and export it as an image, and of course you can use it on windows, as an image. But not as TTF or OTF.

---

Edited.

Design is actually a multy-step process. Probably you can design your basic shapes and styles on Photoshop, for example a callygraphy one. And use it as a base to draw it later in a more suitable format.

Comment: not to mention that Photoshop is not the best tool for working with vectors...

Comment: "there are two ways [...] using Photoshop" ..how on earth do you create a font with Photoshop?

Comment: It was just a question. I want to create fonts with family programs, but I didn't know how to do that. Rafael explained the best way to do my purpose

Comment: @CAI easy export paths as eps and load it in a font maker trough cmd.